# Ctrl-C for exit the program isn't working without enter

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, exit, terminate

I was using Runtime -> addShutDownHook for closing application.
It works with an enter, but only typing ctrl+c doesn't do it's job. Is it because I opened scanner at the beginning of the class? What would be better solution for doing ctrl + c for java?

```
while (flag){
    try{
        a = scanner.next();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        return;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }

    if(option.length() == 1){
        flag = true
    } else {
                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, try to use Scanner = new Scanner every roop than using on constructor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).